# Android network call taking long time

Tags: android, networking

I have a class which extends astnctask, i call a url in it. It takes long time at times to return something, how can I detect this thread call taking long time to connect to the url and unable to get daa from it? 
I want to shut it down like say after 30 seconds...

Answer (score 0):

You can start your async task like this:

```
Asynctask task = new task.execute();
```

Now set a timer for 30 sec and kill it like:

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          task .cancel(true);
      }
    }, 30000);
```

(1 sec = 1000)

Comment: hi, how can i write this in the asycntask class. In do inbackgroun or when setting contrsuctor in asynctask?

Comment: You can have it in the activity right. That way your activity will have knowledge of the ASync task's status